# How can I create 2-man, 3-man, and 4-man basketball lineup IDs out of 5-man lineup combinations?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to take NBA play-by-play data to get lineup specific information, and I'm doing this by creating lineup IDs for each unique combination of players. I'm able to get specific 5-man lineups, but I'm struggling on the best way to slice the df into 2, 3, and 4-man lineups.

Here's a demo version of the dataset:

```
cols = ['defensePlayer1Id', 'defensePlayer2Id', 'defensePlayer3Id', 'defensePlayer4Id', 'defensePlayer5Id', 'offensePlayer1Id', 'offensePlayer2Id', 'offensePlayer3Id', 'offensePlayer4Id', 'offensePlayer5Id', 'points', 'seconds']

data = [[1,2,3,4,5,101,102,103,104,105,3,15],[1,2,3,4,6,101,102,103,104,105,2,12],[1,2,3,4,5,101,102,103,104,106,0,14]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,columns=cols)
```

For 5-man, I'm just using factorize to create a unique lineup id for each combination, but I'm not sure how to approach this when I need to slice the df to where it contains unique 4-player combinations.

Here's my code for the 5-man lineup (p.s. I'm very much an amateur, so if there are glaring inefficiencies in my code, please feel free to let me know). In this case, I'm trying to get a df of each defense lineup and then find the df for every offensive lineup they've faced:

```
df['deflineupid'] = pd.factorize(df.defensePlayer1Id.astype(str) + df.defensePlayer2Id.astype(str) + df.defensePlayer3Id.astype(str) + df.defensePlayer4Id.astype(str) + df.defensePlayer5Id.astype(str))[0]
df['offlineupid'] = pd.factorize(df.offensePlayer1Id.astype(str) + df.offensePlayer2Id.astype(str) + df.offensePlayer3Id.astype(str) + df.offensePlayer4Id.astype(str) + df.offensePlayer5Id.astype(str))[0]

deflineups = df.deflineupid.unique().tolist()

for deflineup in deflineups:
    defdf = df.loc[df.deflineupid == deflineup]
    offlineups = defdf.offlineupid.unique().tolist()
    offdf = df[df.offlineupid.isin(offlineups)]
```

So again, the issue I'm trying to figure out, is how to replicate this with unique 4-man lineups. It's also worth noting that each unique player ID won't always be in the same column. So as a result, the same 4-man lineup could appear in defensePlayer1ID:defensePlayer4ID, or it could appear in defensePlayer2ID:defensePlayer5ID, or it could be split.

If you have any other questions or need other info from me, I'm happy to add anything I've left out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I came up with a likely inefficient solution.

I drop each defenseplayer column one by one, relabel the columns, then append them to a new df.

So the new df has the number of original columns x5, but is only 4-man lineups. Then from there, I use factorize to create lineup IDs for the 4-man lineups.

Again, this is probably inefficient, but allows me to do what I was trying to do for now.

If anyone has a better method, please let me know!